# How to generate code dynamically with javapoet? Change the method parameters

Tags: java, javapoet

I'm trying to generate java code that depends on other variables. 
In this specific moment, I'm trying to generate the code depending on the protocol. So I can receive a CoapResponse object or a Response object form ( javax).

I don't know if it is possible instead of repeating all the code two times with the parameter different if I can reuse the same code and change only the variable in some way.

The code that I want to change is the following:

```
  MethodSpec payloadInterpreter = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("payloadInterpreter")
          .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
          .addModifiers(Modifier.STATIC)
         .addParameter(Response.class, "getResponse")
          ....
```

And the Parameter it could be CoapResponse.class instead of Response.class.

I had the same problem with the Statements but I solved creating literals that use the information that the service received in runtime. 
An example:

```
if (MD.getMediatype().equals("JSON")){
      ReadOutDeclaration="JSONObject readout= null";
      GetReadOut="readout = getResponse.readEntity(JSONObject.class)";
```

and then:

```
 MethodSpec payloadInterpreter = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("payloadInterpreter")
     .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
     .addModifiers(Modifier.STATIC)
     .addParameter(Response.class, "getResponse")
     .addStatement("$L",ReadOutDeclaration)
     .beginControlFlow("try")
     .addStatement("$L", GetReadOut)
     .addStatement("System.out.println(\"Provider Response payload: \" + $L)",ReadOutPrint)
```

I don't know if I can do something similar to this with the parameters or even if there are other ways to do change the generation dynamically.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps:

```java
MethodSpec.Builder payloadInterpreterMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("payloadInterpreter")
          .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
          .addModifiers(Modifier.STATIC);
if (condition) {
  payloadInterpreterMethod.addParameter(Response.class, "getResponse");
} else {
  payloadInterpreterMethod.addParameter(CoapResponse.class, "getResponse");
}
```

and once you want to add it to the TypeSpec, use:

```java
payloadInterpreterMethod.build()
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I could break the builder. This solves my question and it's going to save me a lot of time and code lines!